# "Codabar" barcode generator by Zxing failed in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, barcode, zxing

I want to show QR-code and Codabar code both.

This is my code.

```
var qrcodeWriter = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter {
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions {
        Width = 400,
        Height = 400,
       Margin = 1
    }
};
var qrcode = qrcodeWriter.Write (order.order_number);
imageQR.Image = qrcode;

var barcodeWriter = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter {
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODABAR,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions {
        Width = 400,
        Height = 80,
        Margin = 1
    }
};
var barcode = barcodeWriter.Write (order.order_number);
imageBar.Image = barcode;
```

QR-code success but codabar failed at barcodeWriter.write function.

Please help me.

Error Code:

ex  {System.ArgumentException: Cannot encode : 'T'   at ZXing.OneD.CodaBarWriter.encode (System.String co…} System.ArgumentException

Call Stacks:

MasterBee.HistoryDetailViewController.ViewDidLoad() in /Volumes/Untitled/MsterBee_TEMP/MasterBee/ViewControllers/History/HistoryDetailViewController.cs:69

UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain() in 
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79

UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[] args, string principalClassName, string delegateClassName) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63

MasterBee.Application.Main(string[] args) in /Volumes/Untitled/MsterBee_TEMP/MasterBee/Main.cs:15

Comment: What is your error/exception?

Comment: ex {System.ArgumentException: Cannot encode : 'T'   at ZXing.OneD.CodaBarWriter.encode (System.String co…} System.ArgumentException

Comment: Please add exception and stacktrace by editing the question.

Comment: I added error code

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, I added call stacks

Comment: I am new to Xamarin Studio so i can't find stacktrace. I add call stack instead of stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find reason.

It was format of CODABAR.

Barcodes have each different formats.

So if you make CODABAR with QRcode's format text then it crash.

Additionally, CODE_128 and QRcode's format are same.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Cannot encode 'T'" means that the content which should be encoded can't be encoded as Codabar. Without knowing the value of 'order.order_number' it isn't possible to say what is wrong with the content.
Generally the character 'T' is only allowed at the beginning and the end of the content if you want to encode it as Codabar.
Examples: T1234567890T is ok, T12345T67890T is not ok.

Comment: Thank you for your kind.